# XPath for all the //a[@href] tags in a div with the first /li tag text "Something"

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, testng

I have to find all the URLs from a page in categories. The categories are the first `<li>` tag in a `<div>` tag. The page looks like below.

```
    <div class="c1">
        <ui>
            <li class="d1"> someText </li>
            <div>
                <li> <a href="some url1"> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <li> <a href="some url2"> 
            </div>
            <div>
                 <li> <a href="some url3"> 
            </div>
        </ui>
    </div>
```

How to find all the `hrefs` corresponding to the "someText" `li` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get first locate the `li` element by the "someText" text and then go sideways to get [following sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) `div` element:

```
//li[contains(., "someText")]/following-sibling::div/li/a
```

Or, with [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space):

```
//li[normalize-space(.) = "someText"]/following-sibling::div/li/a
```

(not including the `@href` part as you've indicated you are using `selenium` - you would need to find elements matching the XPath expression and get `href` attribute with `getAttribute()`)

Comment: Hi alecxe, I have a question why din't we used <a> tags directly as a child node for <class c1>

Answer (score 2):

You can use xpath `following-sibling` axes.

```
//div/ui/li[contains(text(), 'someText')]/following-sibling::div/li/a/@href
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to find all the `hrefs` corresponding to the "someText" `li` tag?

### Content-based selection

See [@alecxe's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258729/290085) (+1), but your title and this part of your question,

> I have to find all the URLs from a page in categories. The categories are the first `<li>` tag in a `<div>` tag.

appear to be concerned more with first position than with content...

### Position-based selection

This XPath,

```
(//div[@class="c1"]//li[1]/following::a)[1]
```

selects the first `a` element following first `li` element descendant of the noted `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div[@class='c1']/ui[normalize-space(li[@class='d1'])='someText']/div/li/a/@href
```

Its output is

```
some url1
some url2
some url3
```